# Tagging a GitHub project through Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Our team has recently moved from a locally hosted Subversion repository to a private GitHub repository.  In the past, when we had a build that we were ready to mark as 'released', we would use the 'Tag this build' sidebar link to add a SVN tag on the contents of the build.

With the move to GitHub, I have tagging of a build working in Jenkins, but it only seems to tag the build locally.  The tag displays up if I run `git tag` in the workspace directory, but it never gets pushed to GitHub.

Is there a way to have Jenkins push a tag to a remote repository whenever the build is tagged through Jenkins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature simply doesn't exist yet. Please file a ticket in the issue tracker. I agree that this is an important use case.

Answer (score 9):

> Select 'Push GIT tags back to origin repository' from the post-build
>   actions (this is required to update your centralised git repo with the
>   results of the build).

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-AdvancedFeatures

Comment: That option is not showing up in post-build actions.  There is a 'Git Publisher' there though.  However enabling it did not yield any results.

Comment: @JasonGritman Make sure you scroll up. I thought nothing was happening when selecting 'Git Publisher' and then found some fields were added above my existing post actions.