# Jenkins "tag" build with git

Tags: git, jenkins

There is an option on jenkins when using git to "tag" the build.

What does this do and how do I use it? I assume I can tag the build at that version but I'm struggling to figure out how to push that tag - it's not so useful unless I can push the tag.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't always want to push *all* the build tags, because there could be a lot of them, depending on your build cycle.

But any task scheduler (like Jenkins) will tag a build in case you want to get back to that specific code and debug it (because even though the build might have succeeded, the end result might have run poorly)

That said, should you want to push those tags, you can use, as mentioned in "[Tagging a GitHub project through Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565437/6309)", a post-build action (`git push --tags`).
Or, as mentioned in the [ticket JENKINS-12156](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12156), use the GitPublisher (as illustrated in "[Git, Feature Branches, and Jenkins – or how I learned to stop worrying about broken builds](http://twasink.net/2011/09/20/git-feature-branches-and-jenkins-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-about-broken-builds/)").

Comment: makes a lot of sense... ended up pushing all the local tags

Comment: I'm a little confused. When using the Git Publisher, does "Create a tag for every build" still need to be set?

Comment: Oh, I see. "Create a tag for every build" creates a tag but doesn't give one the choice of what the tag is while the Git Publisher creates the tag of one's choosing. If one uses both, two tags may get created and pushed.