# How can I automatically svn tag build artefacts with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, svn

I'm automating the following manual process with Jenkins:

1. Check out the trunk from svn
2. Build the code
3. Run tests
4. If the tests pass then tag the code and built artefacts

Steps 1-3 are working, but I need some help with tagging in step 4. There are some possible solutions that I've excluded:

- The [svn-tag](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Tagging+Plugin) plugin which has security issues and not developed
  since 2015
- The "tag this build" button which is a manual step and doesn't allow
  me to select which files are tagged
- Using svn command line tools on the slave, because I don't want to rely on them being install (and the same version as Jenkins), also I don't want to expose credentials to the build

Tools seem to be [available for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117736/jenkins-tag-build-with-git). Is there another way to do it for svn that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

What about svn commandline?

Your could try to create a tag using shell :

```
svn copy http://svn/mywebsite/trunk http://svn/mywebsite/tags/2.2.1 -m "Release 2.2.1 - added new feature"
```

Source:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.tags.html

If it works, your **step 4** could be a build step called : **Execute Shell** :

[image]

Just put your shell script in the text-area called **command**. You could use variables for your url, tag number, etc

Finally, you could create a jenkins plugin called **svn command line tool** to make life easier. Is not complex as many believe.

Comment: I'd really prefer to avoid using the command line tools, because it's another thing to install and control on the slave machines. It also requires sending the svn credentials or store them locally on the machine. Since Jenkins has svn and credentials plugins it makes sense to me to utilise those.